# error al crear un procedimiento almacenado con openjson SQL

Tags: sql, stored-procedure

Mi problema es el siguiente : utilizo  sql server express  versión 2017, tengo una variable de tipo json previamente formateada, corre normal en una consulta normal, pero cuando creo el procedmiento almacenado, me sale un error y la verdad no se como solucionar, agradezco si alguien me puede echar una mano entes inconveniente. 
Este es el código en una consulta normal

```
DECLARE @json NVARCHAR(MAX)
SET @json =   
  '
  {
    "varios":[{
    "nombre":"David",
    "cantidad":"291123",
     "numero":"205893"
        },
        {
    "nombre":"pedro",
    "cantidad":"295523",
     "numero":"206693"
        },
            {
    "nombre":"maria",
    "cantidad":"295523",
     "numero":"206693"
        }
    ]
    }
' 
SELECT * FROM  
 OPENJSON (@json, '$.varios' )  
WITH (   
              nombre  varchar(200) '$.nombre' ,  
              cantidad    int     '$.cantidad',  
              numero int '$.numero' 

 ) ;
```

El cual muestra el siguiente resultado

```
Nombre  cantidad    numero
David       291123      205893
pedro       295523      206693
maria       295523      206693
```

pero intento hacer un procedimiento almacenado

```
reate procedure sp_prueba2
@json NVARCHAR(max)
AS
begin
SET @json =   
 '
 {
   "varios":[{
   "nombre":"David",
   "cantidad":"291123",
    "numero":"205893"
       },
       {
   "nombre":"pedro",
   "cantidad":"295523",
    "numero":"206693"
       },
           {
   "nombre":"maria",
   "cantidad":"295523",
    "numero":"206693"
       }
   ]
   }
' 
SELECT * FROM  
OPENJSON(@json, '$.varios' )  
WITH (
nombre varchar(50) '$.nombre',  
             cantidad int '$.cantidad',  
             numero int '$.numero' );

end
```

Y obtengo el siguiente error el cual no he podido solucionar:

```
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Procedure sp_prueba2, Line 29 [Batch Start Line 0]
Sintaxis incorrecta cerca de '$.nombre'.
```

Agradezco si alguien sabe como se puede solucionar o que paso he omitido

Comment: Quita el `; ` del final de `select`

Comment: Lo hice y el error continúa

Answer (score 1, accepted):

al parecer era configuración de mi base de datos el cual no me permitía formatear mi archivo json desde un procedimiento almacenado, asi que lo que hice fue en una nueva query 
ejecute la siguiente setencia SQL

```
ALTER DATABASE GaitanaOnline SET COMPATIBILITY_LEVEL = 130
```

con esto se soluciono el problema y me acpto el json en el procedminto almacenado

Comment: Que bueno que lo hayas resuelto, solo dos comentarios 1) modificar la compatibilidad de la base de datos es algo delicado, te sugiero que leas el impacto general de esto, por las dudas. 2) recuerda aceptar tu propia respuesta, de esta forma nos aseguramos que persista para el beneficio de otros usuario. Saludos.

Comment: Ok gracias si ya lo hice